# MS Access VBA suddenly stops to recognize my enum value causing a type mismatch error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have my custom enum type defined in a module as

```
Public Enum MyType
  Error = 0
  ok = 1
  Cancel = 2
End Enum
```

In another module I have a variable of the type and in a function

```
MyVar = Error
```

This all worked alright, but suddendly I started to get the "type mismatch" error. Autocomlete in the vba editor still works fine and suggests all three possible values for the variable.
I can avoid the error if use fully qualified value like

```
MyVar = MyType.Error
```

I explored the problem a little and found out that if I click on the "Error" value and choose "Definition", Access opens  VBA.Conversions.Error function info. At the same time when I use "ok" instead of "Error" it opens my Enum definition.

The question is why it worked for some time and why it stopped to work and what is the proper way of using Enums to avoid the risk of sudden code break.

Comment: `Error` is a keyword - pick something else.

Comment: Check this [Chip Pearson.- Enum Variable Type](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.aspx)

Comment: @KostasK. Not sure that this is the cause. When you really use keywords like If or Then, the VBA reports about it  immediately. It also stays unclear why Error sometimes works and sometimes not. And mind, it reports type mismatch because it tries to convert VBA.Conversions.Error() to Long, not because it is a keyword.

Comment: @EEM Interesting to read. But does it contain something specific to my question?

Comment: @KostasK. Answered your question. You also wanted to know how to use Enum properly Chip Pearson explains how in a series of pages.